# Lower Priority Queue

Tags: league-of-legends

Imagine that I'm in a lower priority queue. If I join a party to play a game, all the other members in the party must wait that my countdown time run off or we'll skip that?

Comment: Do you mean the penalty for leaving a game early or dodging?  If so then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, if one or more people in a lobby have a lower priority queue the entire group will have to wait the same time they do. If two people have one, but one is longer than the other, everyone will still have to wait for the longest one.

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](http://boards.pbe.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/general-pbe-feedback/8A646W4E-introducing-the-new-leaverbuster-a-new-system-for-aggressively-tackling-leavers-and-afks):

> Players will know how many games they have in lower-priority, and if
>   they join a premade group, that group will be notified they are
>   playing with a chronic AFK/leaver and they’ll face the same
>   lower-priority time penalty.

Therefor, lower priority **does** affect the whole team.